# select some columns to create several files

Tags: r

How to create multiple data frames from this:

```
c1  c2  c3  c100
0.2 0.4 0.9 0
0.2 0.3 0   1
0.1 0.6 1   0.3
```

I want ot select `c1` `c2` and `c3`, the `c1` `c2` and `c4`, similarly `c1` `c2` and `c100`. Each 3 selected columns should be save in separate file.
How can i do in r?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a combination of columns with `combn`

```
lst <- combn(df1, 3, FUN = list)
names(lst) <-  sapply(lst, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse="_"))
```

Then, loop through the names of the 'lst' and write it as different files

```
lapply(names(lst), function(nm) write.csv(lst[[nm]],
       file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```