# Select some column in a loop and save separately

Tags: r

My data frame is

```
c1  c2  c3  c100
0.2 0.4 0.9 0
0.2 0.3 0   1
0.1 0.6 1   0.3
```

I want ot select c1 c2 and c3, the c1 c2 and c4, similarly c1 c2 and c100. Each 3 selected columns should be save in separate file. How can i do in r?

Comment: Should this be done for all variables between `c3` and `c100`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298825/how-to-obtain-all-combinations-of-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-taken-by-2) and then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723202/save-all-data-frames-in-list-to-separate-csv-files)

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday. [select some columns to create several files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699952/select-some-columns-to-create-several-files) .

Answer (score 1):

assuming that `x` is your `data.frame` you can use this:

```
for (i in 3:100){
  tmp <- x[, c(1,2,i)]
  write.table(tmp, paste0("some/file/path/and/name_", i, ".csv"))
}
```

By using the iterator `i` for the file name, you can create individual file names.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combn`

```
lst <- combn(df1, 3, FUN = list)
names(lst) <-  sapply(lst, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse="_"))
lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.table(lst[[x]], paste0(x, ".csv")))
```

---

If it is append 1st and 2nd columns with all the other columns

```
lst <- lapply(names(df1)[3:100], function(i) df1[c(1:2, i)])
names(lst) <-  sapply(lst, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse="_"))
lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.table(lst[[x]], paste0(x, ".csv")))
```